# Are the memory pages belonging to an opened file managed as a vm_area_struct?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, vfs, page-tables

Since I only have the first edition of the book: Understanding the Linux Kernel, I have read some of the source code of Linux 2.2.14, which is very old.

From the source code, I think, that the memory pages belonging to the files opened by a process via the open() system call are not managed by the process's vm_area_struct list. Besides, it seems that the kernel only swaps pages in the vm_area_struct list of a chosen process when necessary.

I know that swapping means the kernel puts some pages to the swap area, and file pages cannot be swapped. However, the kernel can still write back any dirty data and unlink the file pages to get some free pages. So my question is, why the kernel does not try to free some pages belonging to the opened files as well?

Or my understanding, e.g., the file pages are not managed by the process's vm_area_struct list, is completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat confused by your question, I presume it boils down to whether the kernel can under pressure free up physical pages occupied by files. Sure it can and surely it does.

On memory shortage, it may be it makes sense to move part of what's currently in memory to other storage. Anonymous pages land in swap. File-backing pages, if clean, get just evicted. If dirty, get written back first. So in particular they don't end up in swap - why would you put them there if you can do the same i/o and just get the file clean. Note though this could make some sense if the file was backed by a remote fs and it was down at the time, while swap was local.

The consideration with vm_area_struct is a total red herring. I'll only note your mental model here seems to be off. First a minor nit that opening a file does not make the process map anything. Perhaps you meant mmaping a file. The file can be mmapped by multiple different processes at the same time, and even if not and is not open by anyone, the pages can just persist as a cache. Anonymous memory has similar considerations when used - e.g. what happens after fork? Hence while indeed given mm struct will end up having a "connection" to a particular page, there is a layer below.